# xcolors cellcolor overlays tikz background

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tabularx, mdframed

I'm using `mdframed` with the `tikz` option to define my own environment. Unfortunately, if I'm using a `tabularx` environment with `xcolor`'s `\cellcolor` command, it is overlaying the header of my box.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,DIV=1]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
    linecolor=black,
    linewidth=0.5pt,
    topline=true,
    innerleftmargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=0pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=0pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=1.2\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
}

\makeatletter
\def\field{\cellcolor{gray!25}~}%
\makeatother

\newenvironment{ProtocolBox}[1][]{%
    \mdfsetup{%
        style = mystyle,
        frametitlealignment={\hspace*{0.01\linewidth}\vspace{-1.63em}},
        frametitle={%
                \tikz{[
                    baseline=(current bounding box.east),
                    outer sep=0pt
                ]
                \node[
                    draw = white,
                    line width = 1pt,
                    text = black,
                    anchor=east,rectangle,
                    fill=white,
                ]
                {\strut #1};
            }
        }
    }
    \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=\linewidth]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{ProtocolBox}[Header]
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
             \vspace{0.1em}\field The Background of the cell is overlaying the background of the box header
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{ProtocolBox}

\end{document}
```

[image: xcolor background overlaying tikz background]

Do you have any idea how I can define the "order" of the layer, so that the header background is always in front?

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't depend on `tabularx`. Any text you specify in the environment's body will overlap the header. There's no overlap if I remove the `\vspace{-1.63em}` bit.

Comment: Please try to minimize your code and explain a bit what you are doing. Right now, I would just propose to do `\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=\linewidth,backgroundcolor=gray!25]` but I think, this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that would be a workaround. But I would still prefer to be able to define the order of the layer. LariFaRi, I know, that the example is quite long. Unfortunately, most of the code is style definition and I can hardly shorten it, because my problem is a style question.